# jquery ui dialog mvc form validation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4 and JQuery Dialog for form validation . its working fine but when there is validation error like required validation error  it will show partial view separately not in jquery ui dialog box. Can anyone help me regarding this issue ?? Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    //Inside the form there would be a validation summary: 
    @Html.ValidationSummary( ... );    
}
```

When you post the form, the fields would be validated according to your model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display( Name = "Description" )]
    [StringLength( 256, ErrorMessage = "The description must not exceed 256 characters." )]
    public override string Description { get; set; }
}
```

If you want, you can handle the jquery validation and presentation yourself by intercepting the form validate. Something like:

```
$("form").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            UserName: { required: true },
            EmailAddress: { required: true },            
            }
        },
        groups: {
            AllFields: "UserName EmailAddress"
        },
        messages: {
            UserName: "Please fill in user name.",
            EmailAddress: "Please fill in email address.",
        },
        errorPlacement: function ( error, element )
        {
            var container = $('#bb_validationSummary');                
            var list = container.find("ul");

            if( list && list.length )
            {
                container.removeClass( "validation-summary-valid" );
                container.addClass( "validation-summary-errors" );
                $("<li />").html(error).appendTo(list);
            }
        }
    } );             
});
```